# Rhythmbox on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, rhythmbox, ogg-vorbis

Since I upgraded to 13.10, I cannot export CD tracks in Rhythmbox. It told me "Additional software is required to encode media in your preferred format:
Vorbis encoder" I click install, and it loops back and does not work.

I un-installed Rhythmbox, re-installed it, and it still does not work. Now when I click install, I get "Invalid Commandline. The parameters passed to the application had an invalid format. Please file a bug!

The parameters were:
--transient-for=65011715
gstreamer|1.0|rhythmbox|Vorbis encoder|encoder-audio/x-vorbis"

I also renamed the rhythmbox folders in ~/.cache and ~/.local - this also made new difference.

Is this a bug, or do I have something set up incorrectly here?

If it makes a difference, I am running on a Dell D630.

Answer (score 4):

The message is erroneous & a long standing bug. Vorbis encoding is default enabled & if you just went ahead it would work

To 'fix'

Under Preferences > Music > Format settings choose one of the 3 options, for either constant or varible set a quality.

Then close & re-open RB, the so called error will be gone

[image]

after restarting RB the install box will be gone

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by commenting the preset line in the *streamprofile-oggvorbix-1* section of the file */usr/share/rhythmbox/rhythmbox.gep* :

```
[streamprofile-oggvorbis-1]
parent = oggvorbis
type = audio

### Comment the following line by adding a # at the beginning of the line.
# preset = Ubuntu

format = audio/x-vorbis
presence = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually worked, unlike the other answers. I hope they fix this bug soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing vrobis-tool.  To install just click [**vorbis-tool** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vorbis-tools/)

Comment: That did not work - I still get the "Unable to transfer tracks: Additional software is required to encode media in your preferred format:Vorbis encoder". If I click Install, I still get the message above. The debug vorbis-tool version did not give any more information either.